# JSP not keeping indentation of <pre> block

Tags: jsp, pre

I have the following code in my JSP (test.jsp)

```
<pre>
  int main() {
    printf("Hello World!");
  }
</pre>
```

But what I see on my browser is

```
int main() {
printf("Hello World!");
}
```

Why does it left indent everything? How can I keep the formatting of the contents in `<pre>` blocks?

Edit:
Computed CSS

```
box-sizing border-box
color rgb(15, 17, 17)
display block
font-family monospace
font-size 13px
height 304px
line-height 19px
margin-bottom 0px
margin-left 0px
margin-right 0px
margin-top 0px
text-size-adjust 100%
white-space pre
width 785px
```

Comment: What does the computed CSS look like?  Sounds like there's something attached to `<pre>` tags.

Comment: nothing special. im looking at the source code and the indentations are not in the html either.